# Could Not Find statisfactory version from options when trying to install fishtown-analytics/codegen

Tags: dbt

I'm upgrading my dbt version from 0.16.0 to 0.17.2, and trying to update our codegen package as well.

My packages YML looks like this:

```
packages:
  - package: fishtown-analytics/codegen
    version: 0.2.0
```

The error I receive is this:

```
$ dbt deps


Running with dbt=0.17.2
Encountered an error:
Version error for package fishtown-analytics/codegen: Could not find a satisfactory version from options: ['=0.2.0', '=0.0.4', '=0.0.4']
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I Also had some local packages within the packages.yml file which were dependent on a bad version of `fishtown-analytics/codegen`. After, I fixed all the dependencies in the downstream packages files everything imported correctly.